# on insert in textarea change other text

Tags: javascript, textarea

I like to change different content when insert text in `texarea`. E.g. 
If I enter any text in the `textarea` the `id=res` and `id=res2` should change to a static number. Means out of `"-.-"` should be `"2.0"`.

Thank you

html

```
<textarea id="inptxt" ></textarea>
<div id="res" >-.-</div>
<div id="res2">-.-</div>
```

js

```
$("#inptxt").on("change input paste keyup", function() {
  $("#res").html(jQuery(this).val());
  $("#res2").html(jQuery(this).val());
});
```

or see here:
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZVcG4/37/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `parseFloat` function http://jsfiddle.net/vineeshmp/ZVcG4/40/

```
$("#inptxt").on("change input paste keyup", function() {   
    $("#res").html(jQuery(this).val()?'2.0':'-.-');
    $("#res2").html(jQuery(this).val()?'2.0':'-.-');
});
```

Comment: thank you. unfortunately, it s saying "NaN". if I change "1" to "2.0" it doesn't change either.

Comment: sorry this is not what i meant. I'd like to have this: if any content is entered in textarea change -.- to (static) 2.0.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148896/discussion-between-vineesh-and-oliver).